# reading a csv file to pandas using escapechar

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to work with a csv file and read it into a pandas dataframe.
I need to use `escapechar='\\'` but i do not understand how it works.
the code is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, escapechar='\\')
```

but i am getting an error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 23951, saw 8
```

I checked this record in the data frame, the only difference between this one and the rest of the records, which can be the cause of this problem, is one cell with the value:

```
groupe \Data Centre\""
```

in it, written in this exact syntax.
is there a way to be able to read this df, without changing its values, and keep the use of `escapechar='\\'` ?

 thank you very much.

Comment: Can you provide a sample from the dataset?

Comment: Sadly no, these are the details of our customers.

Comment: When I have PII I make up values that mimic the real data so that people understand, and can help provide a solution.

Comment: You can make the data anonymous by sampling and shuffling it, or even hashing the names or other personal info.